# Tag search suddenly broken or changed

Tags: support, status-completed

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server*%20or%20sql%20or%20tsql%20or%20stored-procedures%20or%20mysql%20or%20database) I use to see questions of interest to me has suddenly stopped working. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, we have refactored some of the search code; it shouldn't have *killed* anything, though. The breaking part of that query is the %2a ("sql-server*") - I'm investigating now.

As an update - indeed, the expansion of "foo*" to "fooA or fooB or fooC" has a small pre-existing sneeze, that was exposed by the revised code.

An an update to the update - this is fixed for the next deploy.